# Is there anyway to open a window at the same page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I am developing a website in c#. First I made an example at the wix site. 
I wonder if there is a possibility to open a small window when clicking in a button. 
Here is the example from my wix site.

When I click here

[image: first image]

I want to open this at the same page

[image: second image]

I tried to search a similar question but I couldn't find one.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can use jQuery UI dialog .. check here for more details http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I think using an Iframe suits your needs. It is often linked with javascript, html and css.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help! I think there is here information for me to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a modal window. You can use bootstrap to easily add modal windows on your page like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal&stacked=h). There are plenty of libraries that you can use for that. However, if you want to load a page from a different domain, you can use an [iFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll look through it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make use of modal boxes.

Here are some links which will help you to implement the required functionality,

[BootStrap Modals](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

[How to create modal box?](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Thanks.